# How to update label text when switching to another screen in kivy python

Tags: python-3.x, kivy

Hello I m very new to kivy python programming. I ve been banging my head pass 3 days with this problem. I would appreciate if someone could help me with this.

Basically I have variable called 'SCORE'. On first screen I have 2 buttons. One button called 'Update' which increase value of SCORE by 5 and second button called 'Next' which switch my application to next screen.

My Problem: After switching to second screen there is one label which I would like to display current value of variable SCORE right after I transition to this screen. I m unable to do that only thing I managed to do is SCORE updates after I hit update button but I want to display it correctly before hitting update button.
what should I put in my python code in my class Screen2 for parameter score = '' instead of empty string to correctly load value from previous screen?

I tried global variables, objectProperties nothing seems to solve my problem.
Thank you for any answer or help.

python code:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen

Builder.load_file('design.kv')


class Screen1(Screen):
    app = App.get_running_app()

    def update_score(self):
        app = App.get_running_app()
        app.SCORE += 5
        self.ids.score.text = 'Score: ' + str(app.SCORE)

    def next(self):
        self.manager.current = 'screen2'


class Screen2(Screen):
    score = ''

    def update_score(self):
        app = App.get_running_app()
        app.SCORE += 5
        self.ids.score.text = 'Score: ' + str(app.SCORE)

    def next(self):
        self.manager.current = 'screen2'


class RootWidget(ScreenManager):
    pass


class MyApp(App):
    SCORE = 0

    def build(self):
        return RootWidget()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

kivy file:

```
<Screen1>:
    GridLayout:
        cols:1
        width: root.width
        height: root.height
        padding: 20
        spacing: 10
        GridLayout:
            cols:1
            Label:
                id: score
                text: 'Score: 0'
            GridLayout:
                cols:2
                Button:
                    text: 'Update'
                    on_release: root.update_score()
                Button:
                    text: 'Next'
                    on_release: root.next()

<Screen2>:
    GridLayout:
        cols:1
        width: root.width
        height: root.height
        padding: 20
        spacing: 10
        GridLayout:
            cols:1
            Label:
                id:score
                text: f'Level: {root.score}'
            GridLayout:
                cols:2
                Button:
                    text: 'Update'
                    on_release: root.update_score()
                Button:
                    text: 'Next'
                    on_release: root.next()

<RootWidget>:
    Screen1:
        id: screen1
        name: 'screen1'
    Screen2:
        id: screen2
        name: 'screen2'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this by defining `SCORE` as a `NumericProperty` of the `App`, and just referencing that property in your `kv`.
In your `MyApp`, define `SCORE` as:

```
class MyApp(App):
    SCORE = NumericProperty(0)
```

and in your `kv` you can reference it in both `Screens` as:

```
text: 'Score: ' + str(app.SCORE)
```

and:

```
text: 'Level: ' + str(app.SCORE)
```

With the automatic update, you no longer need to update the `Label` text yourself, so the `update_score()` method (in both `Screens`) only needs to update the `SCORE` itself:

```
def update_score(self):
    app = App.get_running_app()
    app.SCORE += 5
    # self.ids.score.text = 'Score: ' + str(app.SCORE)
```

In fact, since those `update_score()` methods are identical, you can just use one `update_score()` method in the `App` instead of in the `Screens`.

Note that kivy will set up automatic updates to those two `Labels` as long as it can recognize a simple dependency on the `SCORE` property. The use of the

```
text: f'Level: {root.score}'
```

hides that dependency from kivy, so the automatic update does not happen.

Here is a modified version of your code using the above suggestions:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen


Builder.load_file('design.kv')

class Screen1(Screen):

    def next(self):
        self.manager.current = 'screen2'


class Screen2(Screen):

    def next(self):
        self.manager.current = 'screen2'


class RootWidget(ScreenManager):
    pass


class MyApp(App):
    SCORE = NumericProperty(0)

    def build(self):
        return RootWidget()

    def update_score(self):
        self.SCORE += 5


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

And the `design.kv` file:

```
<Screen1>:
    GridLayout:
        cols:1
        width: root.width
        height: root.height
        padding: 20
        spacing: 10
        GridLayout:
            cols:1
            Label:
                id: score
                text: 'Score: ' + str(app.SCORE)
            GridLayout:
                cols:2
                Button:
                    text: 'Update'
                    on_release: app.update_score()
                Button:
                    text: 'Next'
                    on_release: root.next()

<Screen2>:
    GridLayout:
        cols:1
        width: root.width
        height: root.height
        padding: 20
        spacing: 10
        GridLayout:
            cols:1
            Label:
                id:score
                text: 'Level: ' + str(app.SCORE)
            GridLayout:
                cols:2
                Button:
                    text: 'Update'
                    on_release: app.update_score()
                Button:
                    text: 'Next'
                    on_release: root.next()

<RootWidget>:
    Screen1:
        id: screen1
        name: 'screen1'
    Screen2:
        id: screen2
        name: 'screen2'
```

Comment: Wow thank you very much sir. You saved me another 3 days of my time. Also thank you for detailed explanation and tips for code improvement.